# Unable to display HTML Content in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, html

I have below data stored in a rich text are field.

```
<html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class ContentController {
    public List<Content__c> contentList {get;set;} 
    public ContentController() {
        getContent();
    }
    private void getContent() {
        ContentList = [SELECT Id,HTMLContent__c,
                               FROM Content__c LIMIT 2];
    }
}
```

Page

```
<apex:outputText value="{!ContentList[0].Content__c}">
    escape="false"
</apex:outputText>
```

But when i render data in the page it is not displaying content, rather it is displaying html as a text.
`"<html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>"` Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but it worked and rendered my `hello`. The only issues I had were problems you probably introduced when you wrote the question. Please consider editing your question to fix these errors, it won't compile like this! `{!ContentList[0].Content__c}` should be `{!ContentList[0].HTMLContent__c}` - there also is a comma too much in your SOQL `, FROM Content__c` and your `escape="false"` should be within the tag. Since I could not reproduce it, please provide more details about your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. For some reason you are doing the escape="false" at the wrong place

```
<apex:outputText value="{!ContentList[0].HTMLContent__c}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: I am using escape="false" within tag only, somehow it was not given properly here. But still i am not able to get the html content

Comment: I'm not sure about this, the code does not change when you copy it here. I fixed the formatting of your post and saw, that the escape attribute was in the same line, but behind the tag:
`<apex:outputText value="{!ContentList[0].Content__c}"> escape="false"`

Comment: But it is correctly given in my codebase, still it is not rendering

Comment: Hm okay, are you sure it is not escaped in your field already?

Comment: In the fields it is stored like below, <html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>